# Checkstyle for PHP as Eclipse Plugin

Tags: php, eclipse

Is there such a plugin available ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes there's one: [PHP Tool Integration](http://www.phpsrc.org/). The equivalent to Checkstyle is PHP_CodeSniffer (a pear package). You'll find further information here [PHP_CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/).