# PHP (Nette framework) automatic coding standards check

Tags: php, checkstyle, code-standards, nette

I would like to have some type of automatic checking of coding standards for PHP [Nette Framework](http://nette.org/) is there anything like this? Standalone application or plugin for [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/), [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) ... For example to check Java code I use [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/). Or can Checkstyle also check Nette?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261232/checkstyle-for-php-as-eclipse-plugin

Comment: [PHPCodesniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer), [PHPMD](http://phpmd.org/), etc.

Answer (score 6):

Most up-to-date tool is **https://github.com/nette/code-checker** (it's extracted from https://github.com/nette/tools).

Answer (score 2):

There is Nette code checker here: https://github.com/nette/tools

You can also try this CodeSniffer standard written: https://github.com/juzna/nette-coding-standard

Answer (score 0):

**In 2017**, there is official coding standard set to be used: [nette/coding-standard](https://github.com/nette/coding-standard)

If you want to use it, just follow [this tutorial](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/08/14/how-to-apply-nette-coding-standard-in-your-project/).